# Radio button selections to show specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, conditional-statements

Apologies in advance for my lack of javascript knowledge.

I have 2 groups of radio input fields, "States" group and "Structures" group.
There are 4 pricing structures, and each pricing structure is different for each state.

I want the user to select their state and their preferred pricing structure, to reveal a div with relevant pricing information. I also want the user to be able to easily switch between states and structures to compare pricing.

I have it somewhat working here: http://jsfiddle.net/HCreate/L6srku90/
however, I think this is a really long winded solution. The ability to switch between states and structures is not working well because if you select a different state you need to re-select the structure, which is not ideal.

I've attempted to create something more simplified here: http://jsfiddle.net/HCreate/65t6mnd5/
but I have been unable to get it to work. I'm not even sure it is the best method to achieve this.

HTML

```
<p><strong>What State</strong></p>
        <input type="radio" name="groupa" class="wa state" value="wa"/> WA
        <input type="radio" name="groupa" class="nt state" value="nt"/> NT
        <input type="radio" name="groupa" class="sa state" value="sa"/> SA
        <input type="radio" name="groupa" class="qld state" value="qld"/> QLD
        <input type="radio" name="groupa" class="nsw state" value="nsw"/> NSW
        <input type="radio" name="groupa" class="vic state" value="vic"/> VIC
        <input type="radio" name="groupa" class="tas state" value="tas"/> TAS

<p><strong>What Structure</strong></p>
        <input type="radio" name="groupb" class="S1 structure" value="S1"/> Structure 1
        <input type="radio" name="groupb" class="S2 structure" value="S2"/> Structure 2
        <input type="radio" name="groupb" class="S3 structure" value="S3" /> Structure 3
        <input type="radio" name="groupb" class="S4 structure" value="S4"/> Structure 4

<p>&nbsp;</p>

    <div class="waS1 content"><p>WA Structure 1</p><p><em>Pricing Table</em></p></div>
    <div class="waS2 content"><p>WA Structure 2</p><p><em>Pricing Table</em></p></div>
    <div class="waS3 content"><p>WA Structure 3</p><p><em>Pricing Table</em></p></div>
    <div class="waS4 content"><p>WA Structure 4</p><p><em>Pricing Table</em></p></div>

    <div class="ntS1 content"><p>NT Structure 1</p><p><em>Pricing Table</em></p></div>
    <div class="ntS2 content"><p>NT Structure 2</p><p><em>Pricing Table</em></p></div>
    <div class="ntS3 content"><p>NT Structure 3</p><p><em>Pricing Table</em></p></div>
    <div class="ntS4 content"><p>NT Structure 4</p><p><em>Pricing Table</em></p></div>

    <div class="saS1 content"><p>SA Structure 1</p><p><em>Pricing Table</em></p></div>
    <div class="saS2 content"><p>SA Structure 2</p><p><em>Pricing Table</em></p></div>
    <div class="saS3 content"><p>SA Structure 3</p><p><em>Pricing Table</em></p></div>
    <div class="saS4 content"><p>SA Structure 4</p><p><em>Pricing Table</em></p></div>

    <div class="qldS1 content"><p>QLD Structure 1</p><p><em>Pricing Table</em></p></div>
    <div class="qldS2 content"><p>QLD Structure 2</p><p><em>Pricing Table</em></p></div>
    <div class="qldS3 content"><p>QLD Structure 3</p><p><em>Pricing Table</em></p></div>
    <div class="qldS4 content"><p>QLD Structure 4</p><p><em>Pricing Table</em></p></div>

    <div class="nswS1 content"><p>NSW Structure 1</p><p><em>Pricing Table</em></p></div>
    <div class="nswS2 content"><p>NSW Structure 2</p><p><em>Pricing Table</em></p></div>
    <div class="nswS3 content"><p>NSW Structure 3</p><p><em>Pricing Table</em></p></div>
    <div class="nswS4 content"><p>NSW Structure 4</p><p><em>Pricing Table</em></p></div>

    <div class="vicS1 content"><p>VIC Structure 1</p><p><em>Pricing Table</em></p></div>
    <div class="vicS2 content"><p>VIC Structure 2</p><p><em>Pricing Table</em></p></div>
    <div class="vicS3 content"><p>VIC Structure 3</p><p><em>Pricing Table</em></p></div>
    <div class="vicS4 content"><p>VIC Structure 4</p><p><em>Pricing Table</em></p></div>

    <div class="tasS1 content"><p>TAS Structure 1</p><p><em>Pricing Table</em></p></div>
    <div class="tasS2 content"><p>TAS Structure 2</p><p><em>Pricing Table</em></p></div>
    <div class="tasS3 content"><p>TAS Structure 3</p><p><em>Pricing Table</em></p></div>
    <div class="tasS4 content"><p>TAS Structure 4</p><p><em>Pricing Table</em></p></div>
```

SCRIPT

```
function() {
    $('.content').hide();
    if ('.state').checked = true;
    $('.'+$('.state').val()+$('.structure').val()).show();
}
```

CSS

```
.content {
    display: none;
}
```

Would appreciate any assistance. Cheers!

Comment: Learn Javscript first `if ('.state').checked = true;`

Comment: if ('.state').checked == true {  $('.'+$('.state').val()+$('.structure').val()).show(); }

Answer (score 0):

your code isn't working because you need to name your function and you don't have any event firing 
your code.

I would do somethink like these, just to give you and idea:

```
$('input[name="groupb"]').click(function(){

  if($('input[name="groupa"]').is(':checked'))
      $('.'+$('.state:checked')+$('.structure:checked').val()).show();

})
```